# Ag-grid save/restore filter state not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I've been using Ag-grid in my application, and I was experimenting with saving and restoring table filters. ( I'm not-using the enterprise edition of Ag-Grid ).

I found [this link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#saving-and-restoring-column-state) where it says how I can save/restore filters

I'm trying to store the filter state and then hit a URL from which table is updated and then restore the filters

this is my code where I save and restore the filter state

```
 saveState() {
         window.colState = this.tableOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();
         window.groupState = this.tableOptions.columnApi.getColumnGroupState();
         window.sortState = this.tableOptions.api.getSortModel();
         window.filterState = this.tableOptions.api.getFilterModel();
    }

 restoreState() {
         this.tableOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(window.colState);
         this.tableOptions.columnApi.setColumnGroupState(window.groupState);
         this.tableOptions.api.setSortModel(window.sortState);
         this.tableOptions.api.setFilterModel(window.filterState);
  }
```

But, I'm not able to restore to the saved state after I refresh the table data. I tried calling `onFilterChanged()` which didn't seem to do the job for me.

My code looks something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZANfegZ54SAIOmIkaRlL?p=preview)

Need help.
Thank you

Comment: How you are updating your data inside the grid? and what is a flow?
SaveState->UpdateData->RestoreState?

Comment: Initially data is loaded by hitting a URL after which I applied some filters and before I hit that same URL again I'll save the state and then hit that same URL. and after loading the data from the URL I tried to restore the state which didn't seem to work> Filters are not applied after I restore the state

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Ideally, you should also provide a reproduction of the problem (you can start from [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/sVnZAY3smvL1G2VPABYU?p=preview)).

Answer (score 3):

According your sample:

```
saveState() {
    window.colState = this.gridColumnApi.getColumnState();
    window.groupState = this.gridColumnApi.getColumnGroupState();
    window.sortState = this.gridApi.getSortModel();
    window.filterState = this.gridApi.getFilterModel();
    this.http
      .get(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json"
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.rowData = data;
        //... restore the state here ...
        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.restoreState();
        }, 100)
      });
}
```

You can ask why the `ag-grid` doesn't keep current state if `rowData` is changed.

It happened, cuz you are not updating ***existing*** data, you are just replacing the current.

[From the description](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#data)

> `setRowData(newRowData)` is equal of `rowData = newRowData`
>
> **setRowData(rows)** Set **new** rows into the grid.

To achieve state-saving on update operations you should use [`updateRowData`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/) method